# How to send a random photo in TelegramBot using PHP?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to send a random photo in TelegramBot, I wrote this code, but it doesn't work. How do I solve this problem?

#### Code:

```
$pictures = [
  [
    "file"=>"data/pictures/pic1.jpg",
  ],
  [
    "file"=>"data/pictures/pic2.jpg",
  ]
];

$random_image = $pictures[rand(0, count($pictures) - 1)];
if ($text == "pictest"){
    Bot('SendPhoto',[
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'photo' => $random_image,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). $pictures is an array of arrays, but $random_image is selecting an item from an array, so it is getting an array instead of the url associated with file. In the future please avoid saying "it doesn't work" and instead say what didn't work, providing error messages and the actual results and the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we might be missing:

- a base domain before images, such as: `domain.org/data/pictures/pic1.jpg`
- or the `file` index in `$random_image`

  ```
  $pictures = [
      [
          "file" => "data/pictures/pic1.jpg",
      ],
      [
          "file" => "data/pictures/pic2.jpg",
      ],
  ];

  $random_image = $pictures[rand(0, count($pictures) - 1)]["file"];

  if ($text == "pictest"){
      Bot('SendPhoto',[
          'chat_id' => $chat_id,
          'photo' => $random_image,
      ]);
  }
  ```